# * -10709: Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=111:Connection refused in HANA

Tags: hana

I was loading 2 billion rows into SAP HANA and in the middle I got this message and was not unable to load further and the process terminated.

> - -10709: Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=111:Connection refused in HANA

The SAP HANA Server is running but now I am unable to create the database connection. The HDBSQL terminal also cannot be accessible. Could anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Restarting the SAP HANA Server worked for me.